# RestSharp Asp.net VB.net no response

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, restsharp

I am trying to pass api request and get a response on button click in Asp.net 4.61 with VB.net. Then the response will show in a textbox, however I never get a response and it doesnt even seem my login is hitting the API as no attempts show up in the API log. I had something like this working the other day and my stupid hard drive died! Trying to rewrite it but I have missed something clearly. I do not get any errors just no response.
I am able to use postman and get a response to the same url
thanks i advance here is a sample of my code

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json
Imports RestSharp
Imports System
'Imports System.Text.Json
'Imports System.Text.Json.Nodes
Imports System.Threading.Tasks
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim restClient As RestClient = New RestClient("http://myurl.com/ws/rest/userid=myid&password=password")
        ' restClient.Timeout = -1
        Dim request As RestRequest = New RestRequest(Method.Post)
        request.AddHeader("X-API-Key", "MYAPIKEY")
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml")
        Dim body = "MY Body Request XML Redacted"
        request.AddParameter("application/xml", body, ParameterType.RequestBody)
        Dim result As RestResponse = restClient.Execute(request)
      
        MsgBox((result.Content))
        txtXMLTEXTBoxTest.Text = result.Content
    End Sub
```

Comment: Are you able to attach a debugger to the other end to see it is in fact responding to your requests and not doing something like stuck in some loop?  Fact that it's not giving any response (even a time out) would suggest something is being returned and it probably is something in your client end.  What happens if you hard code the body with a known working value you used in postman?

Comment: I did a debugger and it showed nothing relevant as well. Perhaps I can try that again.  I wondered if I needed to do Async for API request but not all too familiar with Async. 
My request is hard coded I was just trying to do proof of concept first before I did anything else. It works perfectly in Postman. Something I am missing within asp.net o vb.net just havent figured out yet.

Comment: Just to be clear, I was meaning attaching a debugger to the remote service, not the above code block.  Also wonder what would happen if you used a stock HttpClient rather than RestSharp.  Don't see any point complicating it with Await/Async if the proof of concept isn't getting anywhere.

Comment: Restsharp is a wrapper over httpClient. You should await the requests.

Comment: @ClearlyClueless can you give me an example if how I should do that based on the code I provided? 
Hursey I cant put a debugger on the service, but I dont think it even connect to it. When I use postman I see in the logs right away when it logs into the API, when I use .NET It never shows that there was an attempted login.

Comment: Are you familiar with the [async/await workflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/concepts/async/)? I can provide you the code to write, which is very simple syntactically, however you would gain more by reading through the article linked above.

Comment: Just a little. I had Async with my old code till my hard drive died. It was the first time I recall using it and dont remember exactly what I did. I'll take a look at the link and reply back if I have more questions. thanks

Comment: `Execute` should work as it uses an internal async call wrapper to call `ExecuteAsync` synchronously. I don't think it's a problem.